# How to dynamically build up a Bool query using the NEST client?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need to be able to add different query types into my Bool query based off some conditions, however I cannot figure out how to do this because the `Must()` function is asking for `params QueryContainer[] queries`

For example this is what I **can** do:

```
desc.Query(qq => qq.Bool(qqq => qqq.Must(m => m.Range(r => r.OnField("lastModified").GreaterOrEquals("from").LowerOrEquals("to")), s => s.Prefix(p => p.OnField("test").Value("query")))));
```

As you can see the `Range` query and the `Prefix` query are used together here, but are comma delimited within the `Must` method.  I need to be able to do something more like:

```
List<QueryContainer> queryList = new List<QueryContainer>();

    // Range
    if (searchTypes.Contains(5)) {
        QueryDescriptor<BackupEntitySearchDocument> qd = new QueryDescriptor<BackupEntitySearchDocument>();
        qd.Range(r => r.OnField("lastModified").GreaterOrEquals("from").LowerOrEquals("to"));
        queryList.Add(qd);

    }

    /// A couple other query types may be added to queryList here

    desc.Query(qq => qq.Bool(b => b.Must(queryList)));
```

And then be able to have multiple other conditions that are checked and possibly added to the `queryList` list.

Does that make sense? Any ideas how I can get this functionality?

Comment: What version of NEST are you using? Additionally, what version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a .ToArray() to the queryList in the must:

```
desc.Query(qq => qq.Bool(b => b.Must(queryList.ToArray())));
```